# Java Multiple Threads Difficulty

Tags: java, multithreading

At the moment I have a simple Stopwatch code that uses System.currentTimeMillis. My program however freezes when I try to get it to update the JTextField that holds the number of seconds that has passed, it freezes. I've searched around and if I've understood it right I can't have the same "thread" run the infinite loop and the GUI. I am a fairly unexperienced programmer and wondering if threads is something I should even try to grasp/learn/implement.

Comment: Would it be possible to show the code?

Comment: You should learn Threads, they can be very usefull especially if you want to optimize performance. But i would start with a simpeler example where a Thread does a simple action then posts the result. It will teach you how to establish communication between Threads. Btw the most probable reason your program freezes is that a seperate Thread cannot post to the UI(not directly atleast).

Comment: Threading is important to understand, but if you're inexperienced there are plenty of other things that are more important to understand first. If you read the Oracle tutorial trails you'll learn how to work with Swing's threading, and why you need to use a `SwingWorker` if you intend to start long running operations on button presses or some such.

Comment: Failing to post the code due to some kind of format error. Seems to be some mixed answers, I guess it would be easier to not go into threads just yet. Is there any kind of simpler "workaround" to getting a textfield to update automatically?

Comment: There is no reason for a stopwatch program to explicitly create any thread.  Use a Swing timer to keep the display up-to-date when the stopwatch is running.  And, when the stopwatch is not running, then all you need to do is respond to button clicks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a different Thread for your business code than the AWT/Swing thread that is updating the UI. If you block the AWT/Swing Thread, the UI will be blocked as well.

Use a new Thread for your countdown and update the UI from the AWT thread, which can be done by SwingUtilities.invokeLater, see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater%28java.lang.Runnable%29

Answer (score -1):

Threads may look scary at first, but it's not as scary as you think. it is also a good place to start when learning extends and implements. Take a look here for some simple examples to get you started: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html